# How to test components with menu

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-popup-menu

I'm trying to test, with Jest's snapshots, a component containing a menu. The problem is that the menu's content is not rendered so I can't test the whole component.

Is there a way to force a menu to render all its MenuOption? I tried to use `<Menu opened={true}>...</Menu>` but the result was the same.

For example, this code will produce a snapshot not containing `foo`.

```
  expect(renderer.create(
    <MenuContext>
      <Menu>
        <MenuOptions>
          <MenuOption>
            foo
          </MenuOption>
        </MenuOptions>
      </Menu>
    </MenuContext>
  )).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Menu` component does not render `MenuOption`s directly to overcome problems with react-native z-index handling. Additionally it needs first to get dimensions of it etc. It would require more steps until you got them rendered in your test.

But the library itself has a lot of tests and in my opinion your test should not depend on internal handling of the library. Instead you should mock it - e.g.

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

jest.mock('react-native-popup-menu', () => ({
  Menu: 'Menu',
  MenuContext: 'MenuContext',
  MenuOptions: 'MenuOptions',
  MenuOption: 'MenuOption',
  MenuTrigger: 'MenuTrigger',
}));

import BasicExample from '../BasicExample';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <BasicExample />
  ).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Note - your mocks and your imports should match! (`Menu` can be imported in two ways).

And then you get nice snapshot - see [example snapshot](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/examples/__tests__/__snapshots__/Basic-test.js.snap)

Comment: What if I'm not using snapshot testing?

Comment: you can assert ("expect") results in any way you like. snapshots are optional. btw - you haven't mentioned that kind of testing you are using